# Protecting public/private keypair in web app

Tags: javascript, security, encryption

My application requires a public and private keypair combo in order to create signed URLs to access our assets from Cloudfront.  The issue I am having is how to protect this keypair so that an unauthorized user could not simply download the keypair themselves, and generate signed URLs without our permission.

I considered encrypting the keypair, but this seems like it would do no good, as the encryption key would have to be stored in the client side code, which is visible in Javascript.  I cannot think of any other way to protect the keypair from someone who is simply able to use Chrome dev tools.

Does anyone know of a way that I can protect my keypair without having to store a secret key in the client side code?  I have already considered code obfuscation, but this technique seems very easy to work around.  I am looking to find out if anything else is possible.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you explain the scenario ?  what do you mean by private keypair combo / signed URLs ? - provide a simple scenario and what you're after

Comment: In general, anything you store on the client (any client, be it a desktop app, in the browser, mobile app on a phone, etc.), a user can access. Not knowing anything about what the actual data flow is, your best bet might be to send the request to a server to perform the actual crypto operations.

Comment: @RoyiNamir the public and private key pair are PEM files.  The basic premise behind Cloudfront signed URLs is that you create a signature string which describes your access policy, hash it using an RSA private key, and verify it using the public key.  This signature is then appended to the URL and verified within Cloudfront.

Comment: Have only descriptions of public keys on the client. Then return to the server where you have your private keys, generate urls at the server and return to the client.

Comment: @WiktorZychla This is an option I have considered, however the downside here is this kills the entire scalability benefit of Cloudfront, which is that I don't have to hit my own servers for each request.  As budget is a larger concern for me than security, I would likely hide the encryption key in code before I would put that kind of load on my servers unnecessarily.  Thank you for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to protect your public key because it's public.

You'll need to sign your urls on the server, not in the browser.

The most secure way to protect your private key is with a hardware security module, but they're not cheap.

The next best way is to protect it with access controls on your server.

Comment: Forgive me if this is a stupid question, but couldn't the user just look at the requests being made in the Network tab of the Chrome dev tools, see how we are obtaining signed URLs from the server, and just replicate the process?  For instance, if I make an endpoint that takes in a URI and returns a signed URL, how would I prevent anyone from hitting that API to get a signed URL?  Forgive my ignorance, consider me a security novice.

Comment: I've played with their signed URLs before. Seemed like short-lived, IP-specific URLs were the way to go. Like sign(your key, real URL + client IP address + valid until time). That way the URL is only valid from that IP for a couple of minutes say

Comment: Right, the issue is that my application is public, so IP-specific URLs will not work out.  Therefore, a server solution is not really more secure.  It will protect my private key, but it will not prevent the user from being able to generate signed URLs without our permission (in fact it will make it easier since they don't even have to go through the trouble of understanding how a signed URL is put together, since it's all abstracted by the server).

Comment: Why do you need to sign these URLs exactly?